# Python | Как получить файл процесса зная только его PID

Tags: python, cmd

Например, у меня запущен хром, и у него PID 1111
Нужно, чтобы я ввёл в функцию значение 1111 и функция вернула название процесса хрома (Chrome.exe)

Как сделать такую функцию?

Comment: Для linux [man 5 proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
from psutil import process_iter

def process_name(pid: int):
    for i in process_iter():
        if i.pid() == pid:
        return i.name()
```